# R: Extract elements from a vector given start/stop positions

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to extract elements from a vector in R if I know the start/end indices for each extraction? For exemple I have:

```
v <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t")
start <- c(1, 4, 11, 15)
end <- c(2, 7, 11, 19)
```

Result should be: `c("a", "b", "d", "e", "f", "g", "k", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
v[unlist(Map(`:`, start, end))]

 [1] "a" "b" "d" "e" "f" "g" "k" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try

```
unlist(Map(function(x,y) v[x:y], start,end))
```

or

```
v[!!findInterval(seq_along(v),sort(c(start,end+1)))%%2]
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is

```
unlist(sapply(1:4, function(x) v[start[x]:end[x]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(start, end, ~ v[.x:.y]) %>%
       flatten_chr
#[1] "a" "b" "d" "e" "f" "g" "k" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
```